# Exclude members from existing Set using MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need an MDX to eliminate some of the members in existing set, my scenario is as below

I have dimension which has n-level parent child hierarchy and I am using that dimension in PPS dashboard. When user selects all children along with the parent then I should not display children and i should only display parent and this is applicable for any level.

Below is the example, assuming that Company is my dimension and it has HR and Finance departments and sub-departments under the main departments (I added primary key of each dept in Parenthesis).

```
Company (1)    
          HR (2)   
                HR Sub 1 (3) 
                HR Sub 2 (4) 
          Finance (5)   
                Finance Sub 1 (6) 
                Finance Sub 2 (7)
```

I am using the above dimension as "Multi Select Tree" in my PPS so user can select HR, HR Sub 1, HR Sub 2 at a time. When selects all child under parent then I need to exclude the children.

Below is the logic to achieve it

First get parent for each member and if the member parent is exists in the selected set then ignore that member. To achieve this I wrote a MDX and I am able to find the Parent of each member but I don’t know how to check whether the parent exists in the set or not.

below is the MDX I wrote

```
WITH SET DeptSet AS '{[Company].[Dept].&[2], [Company].[Dept].&[3],[Company].[Dept].&4], [Company].[Dept].&[6]}'
MEMBER Measures.ParentNode as [Company].Dept].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.UNIQUENAME

SELECT [Measures].[EmpCount] on ROWS, {Need Trimmed Member Set Here} on COLUMNS FROM [CUBE]
```

In the above MDX "DeptSet" is the set which I receive from PPS and after implementing the above logic I need to get the set as below

```
{[Company].[Dept].&[2], [Company].[Dept].&[6]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody please answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Use below MDX to get it done

[DeptSet] - Filter([DeptSet], Count([DeptSet].CurrentMember.Parent - [DeptSet])=0)

in the place of {Need Trimmed Member Set Here}

Look at below link for more details
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlanalysisservices/thread/a020c70c-2986-4f2c-8f4f-366e8be06c2d